# String 'G' is not showing

Tags: c++

So this is the client.cpp file. So what's the problem? I declare this string 'G', I enter the nickname and then here '          cout << G << ":" << sbuffer.Message <

P.S.: I don't think I need to post the server.cpp file, do I?

```
    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

string G;

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ClientThread()
```

{
        Buffer sbuffer;

```
char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

for(;; Sleep(10))
{
    if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL))
    {
        memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
        cout << G << ":" << sbuffer.Message <<endl;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

```
int main()
```

{
    system("cls");

```
int RetVal = 0;

WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    exit(1);
}

sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
getchar();
RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    main();
}
else
{
    string G;
    cout << "Nickname: " << endl;
    cin >> G;

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        char* buffer = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

        cin >> buffer;
        getchar();

        send(sConnect, buffer, 256, NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please reduce your code to a *Short* Self Contained Correct Example. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: `G` is a terrible name for a variable.

Answer (score 5):

The `string G` you declare in the global scope at the top is over shadowed by the `string G` that you declare in the `main` scope and thus the one you read into isn't available to the `ClientThread` method. Delete the declaration in the main scope.

Answer (score 4):

If that's all the same file, then you're declaring G twice, when you only should do it once.

```
// string G;
cout << "Nickname: " << endl;
cin >> G;
```